# C# Log4Net and Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle11g, log4net

I want use Log4Net in my application for logging to console and database(Oracle)

I made this setting :

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%thread] - Level%newline - %level%newlineMessage  - %message%newlineUTC Date - %utcdate{ABSOLUTE}%newlineDate - %date{ABSOLUTE}%newline%newline  "/>                                   
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="AdoNetAppender_Oracle" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <connectionType value="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  <connectionString value="DATA SOURCE= (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myIpAddress)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe))); USER ID=user_name PASSWORD=my_password;"/>
<commandText value="INSERT INTO LOG (Datetime,Thread,Log_Level,Logger,Message) VALUES (:log_date, :thread, :log_level, :logger, :message)" />
<bufferSize value="1" />
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

```
<root>
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_Oracle"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</root>
```

On console I have output, but after start there is some Exception thrown: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

And of course there is no new line in Oracle table.

Any suggestion why not working ?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the dll `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342` is the same as the one you have in your reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working configuration for my custom table but you can use the default columns. Pay attention on which OracleDataAccess use in your application (Version=2.121.2.0) Check here [AdoNetAppender.ConnectionType Property](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_AdoNetAppender_ConnectionType.htm)

```
    <appender name="DatabaseAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionString value="Data Source=HR;User Id=HRL;Password=HR;Max Pool Size=30" />
    <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO HRPORTAL.LOG_WEB (DATA,SESSIONE,ENTITA,DESCRIZIONE,DETTAGLIO,MODULO) VALUES (:data, :sessione,:entita,:descrizione, :dettaglio,:modulo)" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":data" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":sessione" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{sessione}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":entita" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{entita}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":descrizione" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{descrizione}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":dettaglio" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{dettaglio}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
      <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":modulo" />
       <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{modulo}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>

  <root >
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
```